# Unreachable code detected in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This codes showed that unreachable code, is it anything I missied it in here? I'm using C# and ASP.NET. When I was run this codes Response.Redirect("Upload Process.aspx?QuizID=" + id + ""); never reach here.

```
   if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string number = ddlNumber.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string title = txtTitle.Text;
            string level = txtLevel.Text;
            string duration = txtDuration.Text;

            Quiz m = new Quiz
            {
                NumberOfQuestion = int.Parse(number),
                Title = title,
                Level = char.Parse(level),
                Duration = int.Parse(duration)
            };
            db.Quizs.InsertOnSubmit(m);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            string id ="";
            var q = from Quiz in db.Quizs where Quiz.Title == title select Quiz;
            foreach(var p in q)
            {
                id = p.QuizID.ToString();
            }

            for (int a = 0; 0 < int.Parse(number); a++)
            {
                Question o = new Question
                {
                    QuizID = int.Parse(id)

                };
                db.Questions.InsertOnSubmit(o);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            Response.Redirect("Upload Process.aspx?QuizID=" + id + "");
        }
```

Comment: `0 < int.Parse(number)` is not what you want

Comment: Infinite loop... adding a breakpoint and step-by-step will help you find this kind of error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

notice how `number` never ever changes in this loop

```
for (int a = 0; 0 < int.Parse(number); a++)
{
    Question o = new Question
    {
        QuizID = int.Parse(id)

    };
    db.Questions.InsertOnSubmit(o);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

if `0 < int.Parse(number)` is true when you begin the loop, it will continue to be true as the loop keeps executing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not

```
for (int a = 0; a < int.Parse(number); a++)
```

Think about it, when is 0 ever going to be >= than number?